# PUSH NOTIFICATION TAP

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know how to go in a specific activity from tapping on FCM push notification while Android app is in BACKGROUND or KILLED state .

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my chat app, I had done it this way.You can modify it the way you want

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken( token );
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );
    User user = new User();
    user.id = remoteMessage.getData().get( Constants.KEY_USER_ID );
    user.name = remoteMessage.getData().get( Constants.KEY_NAME );
    user.token = remoteMessage.getData().get( Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN );
    if (new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(Constants.KEY_BLOCKED_NOTIFICATION + user.id,false)){
        return;
    }

    int notificationId  = new Random().nextInt();
    String channelId  = "Messages";

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    intent.putExtra( Constants.KEY_USER,user );
    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag") PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this,0,intent,0 );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this,channelId );
    builder.setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher );
    builder.setContentTitle( user.name );
    builder.setContentText( remoteMessage.getData().get( Constants.KEY_MESSAGE ) );
    builder.setStyle( new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getData().get( Constants.KEY_MESSAGE )) );
    builder.setPriority( NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT );
    builder.setContentIntent( pendingIntent );
    builder.setAutoCancel( true );

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        CharSequence channelName = "Messages";
        String channelDescription = "Messages notifications";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel( channelId,channelName,importance );
        channel.setDescription( channelDescription );
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService( NotificationManager.class );
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( channel );
    }
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from( this );
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(notificationId,builder.build());
   
}
}
```